# Universal Windows: How to access the elements in another Page?

Tags: win-universal-app

There are 2 pages in my UWP project.

In the following page, I announce a WebView object.

```
<Page
    x:Class="UniversalMarkdownTestApp.WebViewPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:UniversalMarkdownTestApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <WebView Name="WebContent" Grid.Row="0" x:FieldModifier="public"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Now I want to access this object in other page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried accessing via WebViewPage.WebContent also note an instance of this page has to be created for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access this object in other page by the following code:

```cs
MainPage mainpage = new MainPage();
var webv = mainpage.WebContent;
```

But as AbsoluteSith said, this object's instance has been created, if you want to add it to the new page, you could not add directly.

You would need to use this object's property value to create a new object. Please see the following code:

```cs
MainPage mainpage = new MainPage();
var webv = mainpage.WebContent;

WebView wv = new WebView();
wv.Source = webv.Source;
grid.Children.Add(wv);
```

There's another other way to get object in other pages. You could pass object as parameter when navigating. See the following code:

```cs
rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage),WebContent);
```

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    WebView wv = new WebView();
    wv.Source = ((WebView)e.Parameter).Source;
    gd.Children.Add(wv);
}
```

Here, I still not sure why you want to do this. In general, I don't suggest get controls between the pages. Maybe, if you could tell us your requirement, or What kind of effect you want to achieve, there might be some better solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much! Following you suggestion, I give up accessing objects in other pages and try to implement it by pass the necessary parameter to other page.